# Can I run a .vdi file for Windows 8.1. virtual machine in KVM/QEMU or VMM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

Can I run a .vdi file for Windows 8.1. virtual machine in KVM/QEMU or VMM? Do I need to convert the file from .vdi to some format familiar to KVM/QEMU? What are the steps, if possible?

I have VirtualBox and a Windows 8.1 virtual machine .vdi file created under VirtualBox in a computer. I have KVM/QEMU and VMM in another computer. Both computers run Lubuntu 18.04 as host OS. I am considering to copy the .vdi file to  the second computer and run it there.
I remember Windows 8.1 in the .vdi file has been activated by a product key. Will I be able to have the two Windows 8.1 virtual machines without problem?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Exchanging_images_with_VirtualBox

Answer (score 6):

QEMU can use a VirtualBox-format disk image directly. You can convert them to a “QEMU-native” format if you prefer, using `qemu-img`:

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 yourimage.vdi yourimage.qcow2
```

The fact that QEMU can read such disk images doesn’t necessarily mean that the VM itself will work as it would in VirtualBox; for example, [the VirtualBox images of Windows](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) which Microsoft provides for browser testing tend not to work all that well in QEMU with the original disk images, but work fine when converted to `qcow2` format.

> Will I be able to have the two Windows 8.1 virtual machines without problem?

That’s a Windows-specific question, to which I don’t know the answer; you should ask it on a more appropriate Stack Exchange.